# How to avoid abusing TRY EXCEPT when check API parameters requested?

Tags: python, django, try-except

I have an API which is a `POST`

This API has a lot of optional parameters, so obviously, my code would be something like this:

```
input_data = request.data

try:
    optional_parameter_1 = input['parameter_1']
except:
    **do sth

.............................................

try: 
    optional_parameter_2 = input['parameter_1']
except: 
    optional_parameter_2  = something


................................................
```

In my code there are a lot of it, and I think I am abusing `try` and `except` too much.

I wonder if there is any alternatives way which is short, simple and clean then using `try` and `except`

Comment: Assuming that's a dictionary, have you tried using `.get` instead? That lets you provide a default. Also you should **never** use bare `except:`, in this case `except KeyError:` would likely be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @jonrsharpe's comment, you can do

```
input_data = request.data
optional_parameter_1 = input_data.get('parameter_1','default_1_val')
optional_parameter_2 = input_data.get('parameter_2','default_2_val')
```

Comment: Can we do it, in the case of POST, when a `body` of `json` was sent, because it seems to be the case of `GET`

Comment: You can use request.get_json() if you're using Flask.